# Validate hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using the jQuery validation plugin and I have 3 input fields for date. 
When you enter day, month and year those values are inserted in fourth hidden input field with class full-date and that "grouped" value should be validated to accept only values from data-max-date-adt and data-min-date-adt fields.

I created JSFiddle for this and you can see last input `<input type="text" name="date" data-max-date-adt="22.04.2017" data-min-date-adt="22.04.2005"/>` works like it should when you insert date, but hidden input full-date which collects values from inputs does not.

Here is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q3cndzmm/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `ignore: ""` under `$("#form").validate()` to make hidden inputs validate on submit. Also the `data-max-date-adt` and `data-min-date-adt` were the wrong way round on the hidden `input`.

https://jsfiddle.net/q3cndzmm/5/

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to figure this out all day long... 
Can you please tell me is there any way to validate hidden input on change (when I insert for example year) not on submit?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, you need to explicitly tell jQuery validate to *not* ignore anything:

```
$("#form").validate({
        ignore: [], // Add this
        rules: { ... }
});
```

Because jQuery validate ignore hidden inputs by default.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3cndzmm/7/

Comment: This JSFIddle doesn't work. Thank you for reply, but I will use G0dsquad solution.